# How to serve blazor app from a controller action in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor, blazor-client-side

I've previously asked this question for Blazor around the time when the 3.0 preview was out.
[Is there a way to serve a Blazor app from a specific controller action in a MVC app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58479724/is-there-a-way-to-serve-a-blazor-app-from-a-specific-controller-action-in-a-mvc)

Since then Blazor 3.2 has arrived, I did some research on how to accomplish this, I tried following the examples on this github issue but didn't really manage to get it working.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20642

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public IActionResult MyAction([FromServices] IWebHostEnvironment webHost)
{
    var file = webHost.WebRootFileProvider.GetFileInfo("index.html");
    return PhysicalFile(file.PhysicalPath, "text/html");
}
```

And change fallback in Startup.cs to:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    ...
    endpoints.MapFallbackToController("MyAction","controller")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A mix of Kazbek's answer and this [post](http://www.rtur.net/posts/adding-blazor-webassembly-to-existing-mvc-application) helped me to integrate blazor wasm to the existing MVC site. Now I have wasm served by a controller action protected by `[Authorize]`.